# Yu-Gi-Oh! Episode: Seto Kaiba talks about being a CEO and harming people every day

Tags: episode-identification, yu-gi-oh

I'm searching for an episode where Seto Kaiba is asked not to do a certain action (can't remember the details) because it would harm someone. His response is what I'm really after. He says something along the lines of, "I'm the CEO of a company -- I ruin people's lives every day!"

Comment: cant remember the show very well, but the very first couple episodes really involved him being the ceo of his company, and after that it sorta falls out of the story, other then him being rich.

Comment: Yeah, this was later in the series (from my recollection) -- he laughs at the plea to not harm the person and then gives the above line. Hopefully someone will know. I've put in my search time and just can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is apparently from the episode "[A Duel with Dartz - Part 3](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_-_Episode_179)" (Episode 179, aired in 2003):

> **Kaiba**: So you got a dweeb army. Am I supposed to be scared to attack?
> **Dartz**: Well... only if destroying an innocent soul concerns you.
> **Kaiba**: Nah. As the president of a major corporation, I have to do that every day.

---

Found with the Google query `seto kaiba quotes` which led me to [this compilation](https://thespookyredhead.wordpress.com/2018/04/13/15-of-seto-kaibas-finest-quotes/); tracking down the episode took the Google query `yu gi oh "dweeb army" site:transcripts.fandom.com` which returned the episode's transcript. (Note: page has been deleted and is not archived.)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much!